# How to resize OpenStreetMap tiles

Tags: resize, tiles, openstreetmap, route-me

I implement offline map application by route-me and OpenStreetMap.
I used tile from zoom level 11-16.

But when I convert to .sqlite it very large file size.
that is my first problem.

and second is on map zoom level 16 is very small (text and road detail on map). have any solution for resize tiles on level 16 or any thing is should do.

Comment: Do you mean "how to", not "hot to"?

Comment: Sorry I mean "how to"...

Answer (score 1):

If you just need help generating tiles, go to maptiler.org and give it a try.

(If you need help implementing tiles, a few more details in the question might help.)

(Hat tip:
[Convert a single large image overlay to tiles for Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960405/convert-a-single-large-image-overlay-to-tiles-for-google-maps))

Comment: my big problem is zoom level 16 is very small.

I can implement my application by use route-me open source and tiles from OpenStreetMap.org. but my map is very small and hard to see when display on iPhone.